# Working with Duplicate Rows Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

We have DB with duplicate rows(with duplicate primary key) and we need to handle it in hibernate , is there a way that in HBM itself this can be handled, may be using distinct or some other way, we also have lots of joins on those table.

Thank you

Comment: When you say primary key then how it can be duplicate? pK means unique and not-null. For hibernate an identifier is must.

Comment: Yes the underline table do not have any primary keys , in hibernate mapping we have used it as primary key (the requirement is to use it as primary key) , we have couple of these kind of tables we can say these are exceptions, composite keys are also not a option .

Comment: The only way is adding a new column that is actually acts as a PK or to find out a composite key based on your table. Since you cannot change your DB schema and also do not have any composite keys then you cannot use hibernate for those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate requires that entity table have primary key which should be unique.
Try to change your table schema by adding unique column and make this column your new primary key.

Comment: Changing DB schema is major change :(

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way